# Organizations that send "Advance Notice" or "Prior Notice" to internal teams, how do you do so with Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, organization-wide

At my organization, we need to send communications 24 hours ahead of time to a large number of people within the organization, aka Advance Notice.

I'm currently having difficulty finding a method of sharing what a final email will look like to internal teams. I can send the email to my self and grab the "view as webpage" link, however, because I send a large volume of different emails this is difficult.

For those of you that need to send this kind of prior notice, how do you work around this?

I'm up for anything at this point, whether it be AMPscript, PDF exports, landing pages, HTML exports. I would just like to find something that will auto-update as I change the email and is easily fetch.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please clarify - you are looking for "something" that will be sent only once, and will auto-update with a new version if changes are made, without the need to re-send it?

Comment: Sure, by "something" I meant an alternative to the "View as web page" function. In previous platforms I've used, I was able to grab the link from the preview (prior to send) and if there was an update made on the back-end the "view as webpage" page (upon refreshing) would show the updated version on that live link. 

However, what I am really after with this question, is finding out how other organizations give an "internal heads up" before a communication is distributed within the capabilities of marketing cloud.

Comment: In that case, why not use a CloudPage and paste the content there - you will have a link, and once you update the content, just republish your CloudPage? URL will remain the same.

Comment: That is actually my current solution, however, my main issue is that because of the sheer volume is high of individual emails that are built and sent -- that process of copy/paste would become tedious very fast. I'm looking for a solution to automate that step. So ideally, the landing page would be fetching content from the email (prior to send).

Comment: Ok understood... for now all I can think of is reference content, but I’ve never used it on a CloudPage - maybe worth giving it a shot: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_add_a_reference_block.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Reference content does work somewhat, however, there is a known issue that breaks much of the content when it's a layout block. Really I'm looking for another method I may not have thought of. Thanks! CloudPages issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGkPQAW

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on what's scheduled to go out, you might consider the Approvals feature - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_get_started_with_approvals.htm&type=5. The reviewers would need Marketing Cloud licences/logins to review and provide feedback.